# Inserção de blocos HTML em documento HTML usando PHP

Tags: php, html

Tenho uma interface HTML que deverá renderizar os resultados de consultas no banco de dados (PHP+PDO(MYSQL)) como farei para injetar os resultados dinamicamente na tela HTML(puro)? já que as consultas variam de usuário para usuário (um pode consultar "Tenis" outro "cachorro").

O Sistema funciona seguindo o seguinte fluxo: o usuário acessa uma página HTML *index* onde ele insere a consulta, a consulta é enviada a um arquivo `.php` que processa a consulta e retorna os resultados, para uma pagina HTML(puro) que irá renderizar os resultados da consulta, ela terá a seguinte aparência:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Em vermelho:** Esta a `div` que ira englobar os resultados das consultas (que podem ser variados em quantidade).

**Em verde:** esta a imagem a ser retornada do banco de dados (o endereço dela será retornado e inserido em uma tag img).

**Em azul:** o nome do produto.

O HTML da imagem é o seguinte:

```
<div class="row">
    <div id="conteudo" class="col-md-12 span7 text-center"><!-- START Video Content -->
        <div class="video_block">
            <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
                <img src="../../images/temp/1.jpg" alt="produto"/>
            </a>
            <div class="caption">
                <span class="video_title">Titulo</span>
                <br />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Você vai precisar usar código `PHP` para inserir os dados no `HTML`, para não usar variáveis `PHP`, faça com `JS`. Passe o `PHP` para `JS` e `JS` para o `HTML`.

Comment: @MeuChapeu, desculpe minha falta de conhecimento mas não entendi como sua solução trabalharia, mas muito obrigado pela atenção em responder

Comment: Você pega as variáveis `PHP` usando `JavaScript` e passa para o `HTML`. Assim seu `HTML` fica sem código `PHP`. Como está o código que retorna os dados? Acrescente ele a sua pergunta.

Comment: Eu não percebi o que quer dizer com HTML puro. Sem JS? Sem PHP?

Comment: HTML puro quer dizer que não a código PHP dentro dele

Comment: Então a solução é usar JavaScript mesmo. Como disse o @MeuChapeu.

Comment: poderia dar um exemplo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usando apenas php você pode utilizar a função [createDocumentFragment](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/domdocument.createdocumentfragment.php) ou [creteElement](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/domdocument.createelement.php) e após, dar um append no DOM com a função [appendChild](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/domnode.appendchild.php).

Porém, utilizando `JS` ou `JQuery` você consegue manipular o DOM facilmente: [DOM Manipulation](http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/dom-insertion-inside/).

Answer (score 1):

Não testei o código, mas deve ser isto que procuras.

```
<?php 
$videoperline = 3;
for($videosarray as $videok => $videov){ //$videosarray array com dados do mysql
    if(($videok%$videoperline==0) || ($videok==0)){ //gera linha com base no numero de items
?>
<div class="row">
    <?php } ?>

    <div id="conteudo" class="col-md-12 span7 text-center"><!-- START Video Content -->
        <div class="video_block">
            <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
                <img src="../../images/temp/<?php echo $videov['thumbnail'];?>.jpg" alt="produto"/>
            </a>
            <div class="caption">
                <span class="video_title"><?php echo $videov['title'];?></span>
                <br />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php if(($videok%$videoperline==0) || ($videok==0)){?>
</div>
<?php } 
} ?>
```